# using firebase cloud messaging how can I understand which message give me an error and which message is accepted for delivery?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have a DB in which I saved a list of message that I have to send using firebase cloud messaging.
If I want to send up to 100 messages in batch for better efficient how can I understand which of the message in my db was sended correctly and which one give me an error?

I have seen that the response are something like this for the error response:

```
error: {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Invalid condition expression provided.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest","fieldViolations":[{"field":"message.condition","description":"Invalid condition expression provided."}]},{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError","errorCode":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}]}}
```

for the message accepted we have something like this:

```
id: projects/id_project/messages/0:1563809489349852%31bd1c9631bd1c96
```

How can I understand which message had an error so I can try to send it again or handle that error. Moreover I want to understand even which message was sended correctly.

any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the responses corresponds to the order of the input messages in a batch. From the API docs of the [Java Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging.html#sendAll(java.util.List%3Ccom.google.firebase.messaging.Message%3E)):

> The responses list obtained by calling `getResponses()` on the return value corresponds to the order of input messages.

Same is true for other implementations of the Admin SDK that supports FCM batch messaging.